# SIPdroid Android Studio ndk integration error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, sipdroid

I'm currently using Android Studio 2.0 preview 4. I have followed the guide from [tools.android.com](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) and tested [NDK samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk) from github. The samples worked without a hitch, but when I implemented it on the SIPdroid project, it throws this error when I rebuild the project:

> Error:(78, 1) A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Exception thrown while executing model rule: model.android
>   Cannot set readonly property: minSdkVersion for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor_Impl

when I try to use gradle project sync it gives this error:

> Error:Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.managed.ProductFlavor_Impl'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - You are using JDK version 'java version "1.7.0_79"'. Some versions of JDK 1.7 (e.g. 1.7.0_10) may cause class loading errors in Gradle.
>     Please update to a newer version (e.g. 1.7.0_67).
>     Open JDK Settings
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>     Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>     Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Android project structure now looks like this. previously the jni folder is separated from the java folder. 
[image]

Here's my config:

SIPdroid/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.test.sipdroid"
            minSdkVersion = 15
            targetSdkVersion = 23
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }

    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    /*
     * native build settings
     */
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "SIPdroid"
        /*
         * Other ndk flags configurable here are
         * cppFlags.add("-fno-rtti")
         * cppFlags.add("-fno-exceptions")
         * ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log"])
         * stl       = "system"
         */
    }

    android.sources {
        main.java {
            source {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
        }
        main.jni {
            source {
                srcDirs = []
            }
        }
        main.jniLibs {
            source {
                srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']
            }
        }
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
        create("x86-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86_64")
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips")
        }
        create("mips-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips64")
        }
        // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
        create("all")
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

SIPdroid/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'
//        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

SIPdroid/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Mon Jan 04 16:06:26 PHT 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

SIPdroid/local.properties

```
ndk.dir=/path/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=/path/Android/sdk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recently solved my issue by adding this to my orignal app/build.gradle file without using the experimental gradle build  ('com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0') as indicated in the google samples.

This solution finally solved the issue [NDKBuild Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738953/ndkbuild-failure). This additional script builds your jni files using ndkBuild.

app/build.gradle

```
sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' // use the jni .so compiled from the manual ndk-build command
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
//        commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath <-- Not working
        commandLine '/home/user/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
```

SIPdroid/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
}
```

You also need to have an empty libs folder under app/src/main. My mistake was that I renamed the /jni folder to /libs. After running the build, it will compile your jni to the /libs folder to .so files

[image: app/src/main contents]

jniLibs in your Android project structure view will look like this. This is from your app/src/main/libs as indicated in your build.gradle script

[image]

I hope this helps.