# Android Studio NDK Build trouble Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseNdk'

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

I'm using the latest android studio build 1.5 ,since i want to import an eclipse project that needs NDK. My project is working. But when i built APK, It's make error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseNdk'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Users\Android\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd''
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "vaeapp.gamecard.vn"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled = true
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3.4"

        ndk {
            moduleName "gc"
        }
    }
    // call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        } else {
            commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        }
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
    // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/error-reporter.jar')
    //compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
    // compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
}
```

Please help my fix error. Thanks you!

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using only this

```
 // call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        } else {
            commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        }
    }
```

Use this

```
 // call regular ndk-build(.cmd) script from app directory
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
            commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        } else {
            commandLine 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
        }
    }

   tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
```

Comment: i try it, but it's make error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'ndk-build.cmd''

Comment: @HoangAloevera see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738953/ndkbuild-failure

Comment: @HoangAloevera just give the `ndk-build` path to it .

Comment: ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Android\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle i dont know how to use it?

Comment: @HoangAloevera this is the path.

Comment: yes, but i dont know how to fix row:  commandLine 'ndk-build.cmd'. what can i change?

Comment: I am getting same problem.plz tell me the solution

Comment: You should add NDK for android studio or reinstall it